# How to increase size of UIView inside viewDidLoad method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I am very new in ios application. I have 3 views on my main view. These views are representing a graph. anytime user opens main view (I mean each time viewDidLoad gets called) I need to measure some numbers and draw these graphs according to them. I only need to change the width of the graph! However I tried to manually add size to one of the graph but did not change at all! any suggestion will be appreciated.

As you can see I have added 100 here

```
self.timerGraph.frame.size.width+100


self.timerGraph.frame = CGRectMake(self.timerGraph.frame.origin.x,self.timerGraph.frame.origin.y,self.timerGraph.frame.size.width+100,self.timerGraph.frame.size.height);
```

But it is not affected!

Edit: I used this but Ben is printing but the width is not changing!!

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)try{

    NSLog(@"Ben");
    self.bestGraph.frame = CGRectMake(self.bestGraph.frame.origin.x,self.timerGraph.frame.origin.y,self.timerGraph.frame.size.width+130,self.timerGraph.frame.size.height);

}
```

Edit: I have deleted some implementation parts to make it shorter.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{


    NSNumber *min = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    NSNumber *max = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    NSNumber *avg = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    NSNumber *total = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];


    [super viewDidLoad];
    bool first = true;
    //Find the worst and best and average graph
    for(int i=0;i<tmp.numberOfTimes;i++)
    {
        //LTTime *myTime = [[LTTime alloc] init];
        LTTime *tmpTime = [tmp timeAtIndex:i];
        if(first)
        {
            first = false;
            min = tmpTime.time;
        }
        if(min>tmpTime.time)
        {
            min = tmpTime.time;
        }
        if(max<tmpTime.time)
        {
            max = tmpTime.time;
        }
        total = @( [tmpTime.time intValue] + [total intValue] );

    }
    avg = @( [total floatValue]/tmp.numberOfTimes);

    self.bestGraph.frame = CGRectMake(self.bestGraph.frame.origin.x,self.timerGraph.frame.origin.y,self.timerGraph.frame.size.width+130,self.timerGraph.frame.size.height);

    }
```

Definition of view:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *bestGraph;
```

[image]

Comment: We need more information. Can you post your viewDidLoad Method? Are you using an xib?

Comment: Check if the control is reaching the setting frame code

Comment: @codingVoldemort Yes I have a NSog which getting print out whenever I pass that point

Comment: And see if your views are connected to your class.

Comment: @codingVoldemort have a look at my edited question. Is that what you mean by connecting to the class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60363/discussion-between-codingvoldemort-and-bernard).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was ios autolayout was ticked so I was not able to add in that way. So I decided to create my own view and anytime it goes to `ViewWillAppear` delete everything from view and add them again (because the view was changing more often).

I think it is better to learn how to create GUI elements by hand instead of IButton.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your code in

```
 - (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
```

method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it is true according to your project.

Try the same code in `viewWillAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`.

`viewDidLoad` calls only once when the app runs for the first time.

Hope it will helpful for you. Thank you :)